# Dynamic Polygon JSON array into calculated Geometry Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, arcgis

I have a SQL Server column that contains a JSON array (series of point coordinates) that make up the shape of a polygon. This is properly formatted JSON which is an array of Points. I want to convert this JSON array into a calculated geometry column. The below example is ONE record, but I need the column to be calculated since I am getting this data live into the database.

```
[
    {"X":-135.4993896484375,"Y":40.8944206237793},
    {"X":-135.49931335449219,"Y":40.89435958862305},
    {"X":-135.4993667602539,"Y":40.89413070678711},
    {"X":-135.49922180175781,"Y":40.8939094543457},
    {"X":-135.49891662597656,"Y":40.89371109008789},
    {"X":-135.49922180175781,"Y":40.89352035522461},
    {"X":-135.49994659423828,"Y":40.89336013793945},
    {"X":-135.5006332397461,"Y":40.893218994140625},
    {"X":-135.50110626220703,"Y":40.892738342285156},
    {"X":-135.4993896484375,"Y":40.8944206237793}
]
```

My new column can be called Shape or anything really. How do I parse this and combine it with STPolyFromText to get this into a new calculated column?

Answer (score 1):

```
create or alter function dbo.jsonpolygon(@j nvarchar(max))
returns geometry
as
begin
    declare @geom geometry;
    
    select 
        @geom = 'POLYGON(('+string_agg(concat(v.X, ' ', v.Y), ',') within group (order by j.[key])+'))'
    from openjson(case when isjson(@j) = 1 then @j end) as j
    cross apply openjson(case when isjson(j.value) = 1 then j.value end)
    with
    (
        X varchar(100),
        Y varchar(100)
    ) as v;
    
    return(@geom);
end
go


create table xyz -- table
(
json nvarchar(max),
geom as dbo.jsonpolygon(json)
)
go

insert into xyz(json)
values(
'[
    {"X":-135.4993896484375,"Y":40.8944206237793},
    {"X":-135.49931335449219,"Y":40.89435958862305},
    {"X":-135.4993667602539,"Y":40.89413070678711},
    {"X":-135.49922180175781,"Y":40.8939094543457},
    {"X":-135.49891662597656,"Y":40.89371109008789},
    {"X":-135.49922180175781,"Y":40.89352035522461},
    {"X":-135.49994659423828,"Y":40.89336013793945},
    {"X":-135.5006332397461,"Y":40.893218994140625},
    {"X":-135.50110626220703,"Y":40.892738342285156},
    {"X":-135.4993896484375,"Y":40.8944206237793}
]'
), ('12345'), ('[12345]');

/* this will break the calculated column
insert into t(json)
values(
'[
    {"X":-135.4993896484375,"Y":40.8944206237793}
]'
)
*/

select *
from xyz;
go

drop table xyz
go
drop function dbo.jsonpolygon
go
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this work using a column? I used the XY values as an example for one cell but in reality I have thousands of records and need the ability to just enter the column name.

Comment: ..@zanzibarjack . yes, it will work for a table, you could add a computed geometry column. If you are sure that all json rows will return a valid polygon, then all you have to do is: `alter table tableX add geomY as dbo.jsonpolygon(jsoncolumnZ)` , just replace tableX and geomY&jsoncolumnY with the corresponding names (table&computed column name that you want,column name which holds the json data ). It is possible make the function less error prone: a polygon requires at least 4 points and the starting point == ending point and you could incorporate that in the function dbo.jsonpolygon().